# A solution to replace text without changing layout (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace text without changing the surrounding tags.
 $("content").text("some new text") will remove the surrounding tags.

```
<div id="content" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: px;">
<p><strong>I need to be replaced</strong>
</p></div>

<div id="content" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 5px;">
<p><em><strong>I need to be replaced</strong></em></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that you are always replacing the text in the strong tag, you could do.  Otherwise, you might have to create some sort of business rule to figure out what element in the content block you are going to be replacing.

```
$("#content strong").text("some new text")
```

If you know nothing about the enclosing tags, other than there might be a structure, you could write something like:

```
$.each($('.content'), function(i, val) {
  console.log($(val));
  replaceText(val, 'This is the updated text');
});

function replaceText(element, text) {
    if ($(element).children().size() == 0) {
       $(element).text(text);
       return;
    } 
    replaceText($(element).children()[0], text);
}
```

This will look for children of the current object and if there are children, move down the DOM tree, on the first child.  Now, if an element has multiple children, and you don't know what child you're trying to replace, you would have to do more work to create the business rules.

You could also use a content selector in CSS, if you know some or all of the text that you are trying to replace:

```
$('.content').find(':contains("I also need to be replaced")').text('Update text');
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u13akrp/3/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the problem is that the layout of the surrounding tags is not known , so i don't know if it is a strong, i, p div or other tag. only that the text should be replaced. I hope for a simple solution in javascript or jquery

Comment: If you know which elements can occur, you can do it with Brian's suggestion. If not, you're pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution, very helpful!

re: You could also use a content selector in CSS, if you know some or all of the text that you are trying to replace:

that whas the key :). $("#content").text() == the content we wanted to replace,

Your solution works good.
i finaly made this:

```
var content = $("#content").text();
$("#content").html($("#content").html().replace(content,"new text"));
```

Thanks !